# Java EE 7 Restful Webservice POST method require ID type Autoincrement

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I am using [this Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) to Create simple Java EE 7 Webservices using Netbean 7.3.1.

It run successfully, I am testing using GET, PUT, POST, DELETE. All three are working fine except POST.

I am posting this json data with ID in it, which works fine.

```
{"id":"2","address1":"pe3","address2":"address line1","address3":"Address line3","city":"City Name","town":"Town Name","country":"uk","postcode":"123123"}
```

But because my ID is auto-increment, So when I POST following json without id, it fails with bellow error

```
{"address1":"pe3","address2":"address line1","address3":"Address line3","city":"City Name","town":"Town Name","country":"uk","postcode":"123123"}
```

ERROR is

```
HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request

type Status report

messageBad Request

descriptionThe request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

Can anyone explain why I need to send ID which is auto-increment type in database while send POST? Is there any work around?

code in entity Class is

```
.......
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;

        @Size(max = 45)
        @Column(name = "address1")
        private String address1;

        @Size(max = 45)
        @Column(name = "address2")
........
```

and AddressFacadeREST.java class looks like this.

```
package entities.service;

import entities.Address;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;


@Stateless
@Path("entities.address")
public class AddressFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Address> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CustomerDBPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public AddressFacadeREST() {
        super(Address.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(Address entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void edit(Address entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Address find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<Address> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<Address> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code for the id property of the entity, and the constructors for the entity itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is generated by jax-rs service not being able to convert the json provided into an instance of the entity class. Based on how NetBeans create Entity classes and service facades, your entity class has only one not-empty constructor, and it requires the id as an input parameter. Moreover, you have a `@NotNull` annotation in the `@Id` class. If so:

- Create a constructor that takes all the entity properties except the `@Id` property. This way, the service will be able to convert the incoming json into an instance of your entity class.
- Remove the `@NotNull` annotation in order to avoid the JavaBeans Validator to raise an error when persisting the new entity.

Comment: Once I remove '@NotNull' and '@Basic' annotation, it worked fine without ID for POST. But after doing this change, it also accept PUT without ID and rather than updating existing record, it creates New record. Is this correct behavior?

Comment: The PUT method creates a new record because `AbstractFacade#edit()` method uses `EntityManager#merge()`, that creates a new copy of the object if it doesn't exist, as explained [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting). If you like, you can obviously modify this behavior as per your needs, i.e. by checking if an ID is given and acting consequently.